# Why does this simple MySQL query not return the row?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, null

I have a row in the table `users` with the username `test`. For some reason, though, this query returns an empty result set.

```
SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = "test" AND `id` != null;
```

However, if I remove the `` `id` != null `` segment, the query returns the result `id = 1`.

But `1` != `NULL`. How is this happening?

The `id` field is non-nullable and is auto-increment.

Thanks!

Comment: But why do you check for `NULL` at the first place if the `id` field is non-nullable?

Comment: It's a generated query. I run another method in my class that converts a PHP variable to a properly formatted/escaped value for a MySQL query. If possible, I would like to be able to use the same comparator for different types. In my case, `NOT (column <=> any_escaped_value)` worked.

Comment: Ok, but nevertheless, checking for `NULL` is just pointless if "the `id` field is non-nullable". So you might want to modify the conditions under which the query is generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query doesn't return a row because the predicate " `id != NULL` " will never return TRUE.

Th reason for this is that boolean logic in SQL is three valued. A boolean can have values of `TRUE`, `FALSE` or  `NULL`.

And an inequality comparison will return `NULL` whenever one (or both) of the values being compared is `NULL`.

The SQL standard means to compare to a NULL is to use `id IS NULL` or `id IS NOT NULL`. MySQL also adds a convenient null-safe comparison operator which will return TRUE or FALSE:

`col <=> NULL`.  Or, in your case  `NOT (col <=> NULL)`

Comment: Although I failed to mention it in my question, this response in particular solved my problem, because in `NOT (col <=> NULL)`, I can check against any type, e.g. I can use `NOT (col <=> "a string")` as well.

Comment: @M Miller: that null-safe comparison operator `<=>` is an extension specific to MySQL, but it is very convenient. To emulate that in other DBMS, you'd need code like this: `(a=b OR (a IS NULL AND b IS NULL) )`.

Answer (score 3):

Your method of checking for NULL is probably the issue.  In MySQL, try the following:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = "test" AND `id` IS NOT NULL;
```

To check for NULL and an empty string, you can use:

```
SELECT `id` 
FROM `users` 
WHERE `username` = "test" 
AND (`id` IS NOT NULL OR `id` != "");
```

Comment: !="" is a very different thing. What that's checking for is an empty value.  Please keep in mind that NULL (undefined) is very different from an empty string ("").  Therefore, the query will require two different checks.

Comment: In general, you are right. But as the `id` field is said to be non-nullable, checking for `NULL` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Apologies, but I didn't see where the id field was non-nullable.  Perhaps I glossed over it?

Comment: Duh, I'm a moron.  I missed that last sentence.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try using **IS NOT NULL**

```
SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = "test" AND `id` IS NOT NULL
```

Have a look at the difference

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a612/1)

Comment: Is there any way to do this using the same operator? I wrote another script for generating the query. No way I can use `!=` and include a type check (like the PHP equivalent, `!==`)?

Comment: In general, you are right. But as the `id` field is said to be non-nullable, checking for `NULL` doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

By database definition in general ,Null is nothing and cannot be equated or compared with any other value. Hence ID=NUll or ID!=null wouldn't work.

Comment: That doesn't mean that it can't be equated using `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`. Something != nothing and nothing = nothing.

Comment: Fair enough. My intention was to say that we cannot use regular comparison operators. I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = "test" AND `id` != '';
```

OR

```
SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = "test" AND `id` iS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: The problem is the comparison against NULL, not that it could be an empty string or just a space.