# MYSQL "not equal to" on enum

Tags: mysql, enums

I created a table with an enum column as follow

```
create table test_1(
    id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    order_billing_status ENUM ("BILLING_IN_PROGRESS") DEFAULT NULL
);
```

I insert two values as follow

```
+-----+----------------------+
| id  | order_billing_status |
+-----+----------------------+
| 100 | NULL                 |
| 200 | BILLING_IN_PROGRESS  |
+-----+----------------------+
```

Now when I try to query like `select * from  test_1 where order_billing_status <> "BILLING_IN_PROGRESS";`, it is returning empty result, instead of returning the following.

```
+-----+----------------------+
| id  | order_billing_status |
+-----+----------------------+
| 100 | NULL                 |
+-----+----------------------+
```

Is this a bug in mysql or am I doing something wrong? If it's a bug, is there a work around or should I just use varchar instead of enum?

Comment: Try using single quotes rather than double quotes.

Comment: Why would you have an enum column and allow nulls?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this simple MySQL query not return the row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598682/why-does-this-simple-mysql-query-not-return-the-row) There might be a better dupe target somewhere. Not sure. But misunderstanding how `NULL` is an extraordinarily common problem and has nothing to do with enums.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the `NULL` value check we need to use the `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`

`=` or `<>` ignores the `NULL`

```
select * from  test_1 
where order_billing_status <> "BILLING_IN_PROGRESS"  OR order_billing_status IS NULL
```

Comment: I didn't know that = or <> ignores the NULL. Is this specific to enum ?

Comment: No, it is for all datatype... for string, int also when we need to compare the NULL then we have to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
select * from  test_1 
where order_billing_status<>'BILLING_IN_PROGRESS'
or order_billing_status is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from  test_1 where order_billing_status != "BILLING_IN_PROGRESS";
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `<>` ignores`null`. Just use  keywords like `is not null` or `is null` to check for null values.